# Ehcache: How to swap to the diskStore when Terracotta server is off-line?

Tags: java, caching, ehcache, terracotta

I need to configure my app to swap from the Terracotta server configuration to the diskStore when the Terracotta server is unavailable. Is there a way to do this?
When I configure the terracottaConfig element on the ehcache.xml I can't start-up the application if the Terracotta server was unreachable.... 
This is my ehcache.xml configuration:

```
    <ehcache xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="ehcache.xsd" name="gpCacheManager">

    <diskStore path="java.io.tmpdir" />

    <terracottaConfig rejoin="true">
        <tc-config>
            <servers>
                <server host="XXX.XXX.XXX.XX" name="host1">
                </server>
            </servers>
            <clients>
                <logs>app/logs-%i</logs>
            </clients>
            <nonstop immediateTimeout="true" timeoutMillis="3000">
                <timeoutBehavior type="localReads" />
            </nonstop>
        </tc-config>
    </terracottaConfig>

    <defaultCache maxElementsInMemory="10000" eternal="false"
        timeToIdleSeconds="120" timeToLiveSeconds="120" overflowToDisk="false"
        diskPersistent="false" diskExpiryThreadIntervalSeconds="120"
        memoryStoreEvictionPolicy="LRU">
        <terracotta clustered="true">
            <nonstop immediateTimeout="false" timeoutMillis="3000">
                <timeoutBehavior type="localReads" />
            </nonstop>
        </terracotta>
    </defaultCache>

    <cache name="oxmCache" maxElementsInMemory="10000" eternal="false"
        timeToIdleSeconds="240" timeToLiveSeconds="240" overflowToDisk="false"
        diskPersistent="false" diskExpiryThreadIntervalSeconds="240"
        memoryStoreEvictionPolicy="LRU">
        <terracotta clustered="true">
            <nonstop immediateTimeout="false" timeoutMillis="3000">
                <timeoutBehavior type="localReads" />
            </nonstop>
        </terracotta>
    </cache>

</ehcache>
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid using the disk (on the client) isn't a supported feature as of now. 
Basically if I get you right, you'd like to have entries being spilled on disk rather than on the terracotta server, when it is unavailable.

Now, I guess you'd also want reconciliation when the server comes back, right ? Cause I have a hard time seeing how having (partial) data on disk is useful... Do you care to elaborate ?

Comment: The real problem is that I can't use the application off-line (without a Terracotta server). If there is a way to start the application without an available Terracotta server I'll manage the partial data on disk for reconciliation when the server will be available...